# How many caesium clocks are there on each GPS satellite ? Is there any other atomic clock on-board?

Tags: gps, atomic-clocks

I am trying to find how many caesium atomic clocks are carried by each of the GPS satellites. And whether the satellites also carry other atomic clocks, such as rubidium or hydrogen clocks.

Answer (score 6):

https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2002/08apr_atomicclock/: "Each of the 24 GPS satellites carries 4 atomic clocks on board." Maybe something has changed since then.

EDIT (10/01/17):http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/navstar-2.htm : "GPS-2 (Global Positioning System) or Navstar-2 (Navigation System using Timing And ranging) are improved satellites of the second generation of the GPS navigation system...Each spacecraft carried 2 rubidium and 2 cesium clocks."

EDIT (10/01/17): @MartinBeckett : the following document seems recent: ftp://tycho.usno.navy.mil/pub/gps/gpsb2.txt "The design life of the Block II/IIA satellite is 7.3 years; each contain four atomic clocks:  two Cesium (Cs) and two Rubidium (Rb)...The design life of the Block IIR satellite is 7.8 years; each contains three Rb atomic clocks"

EDIT (Feb 23, 2022):

> There are currently several dozen GNSS satellites in orbit. GPS and
> GLONASS satellites carry Rb (rubidium) and Cs (caesium) frequency
> standards, whereas Galileo satellites are equipped with PHM (passive
> hydrogen maser) and Rb clocks. In the case of BeiDou, the clocks used
> are of either Rb or HMAC (Hydrogen Maser Atomic Clock) standards

(https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/21/7/2396/htm )

See also https://qzss.go.jp/en/technical/satellites/index.html Looks like the answer to your question may depend on the generation of the satellite system.

Comment: Block I and early II had 2 ceasium and 2 rubidium, the new ones are all ceasium, there was a set where (IIRC)  the two rubidium were removed but only one extra ceasium was fitted . The details are in an answer of mine to another question but I can't find it

Comment: That only covers the Navstar satellites; what atomic clocks are carried by non-US GPS satellites (such as GLONASS, Galileo, Baidu)?

Comment: @Vikki : Please see my 2022 EDIT.